# Multithreading - Do I need this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am just trying to check if implementing multiple threads for this processing task would actually speed up processing time. I'm thinking it won't but want to be sure.

Example: Say I want to read in every byte of a file, and then output each byte to a new file. *I don't want to do this but just hear me out.*

So if I begin to output each byte serially in a loop to a new file, would it speed up the process if I instead, for example, broke the file into multiple pieces and then read in and wrote out those pieces in different threads?

I am thinking it won't because even though the threads are separated and can run their own serial executions, you're still having to put it through the processor so ultimately, all bytes are executed individually and never actually simultaneously.

Caveat: I am not talking about the differences in machines with multiple cores vs. single cores. I am wondering for each individual computer. If I ran a version that wasn't multithreaded on one machine vs. a version that was multithreaded, would there actually be an increase in speed?

*I know I could write a program to do this and test it but want to check first if I am thinking about this the right way.*

Thanks.

Comment: Creating a test app would not take long at all, so you should do that.  That said, it really is a matter of considering where the bottlenecks are and, as you suggest, the fact that there are multiple tasks that, at least in theory, can be executed simultaneously is not a guarantee that they will.  For instance, if only one byte can be written to the physical disc at a time then a single stream of multiple bytes is likely going to be faster than multiple streams of a single byte each.

Comment: In my view its more about preventing waiting on slow tasks than 'speeding up' take your file writing example. on the face of it it seems like a single pipeline. but even here you may have two disks or a 'copying x%' spinner etc

Comment: You can probably come up with configuration that will provide almost any predefined result - normally I'd expect almost no difference due to heavy caching of disk IO (or SSD), but you should be able to get from much slower multithreaded version (single slow disk with a lot of random reads/writes) to much better performance in multithreaded version (i.e. for separate read and write disks and sequential writes).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the hardware you're using and what you're processing.  If you're doing a lot of harddrive reading and writing than your bottleneck will probably be disk read write operations more than the CPU.  If you're doing a lot of processing in RAM, then multithreaded will absolutely speed up your processing on a multi-core machine.

Comment: Exactly. The task described in the question is inherently [I/O bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound). You'll get benefits from multithreading for tasks which are [CPU bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound).